# cout always prints my double as 0

Tags: c++, math, cout

My problem is simple really. I needed to make this calculation and display it on the screen to the hundredth:

```
double test = (500/1423)*10;
cout << setprecision(3) << test;
```

I would think I would receive the output 3.51 but instead I recieve 0.
It must have something to do with dividing numbers to come up with a product of less than 0. How do I get the output of 3.51 only using the 3 numbers I used in the code above?

Comment: Maybe the value *is* 0..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result is stored in a double but the constants are integers.

Fix:

```
double test = (500.0/1423.0)*10;
cout << setprecision(3) << test;
```